# Image not showing in imageview as per if else condition

Tags: android, if-statement, imageview, picasso, android-glide

I have to set drawable images to an imageview in a listview. I am using base adapter class.

There are two types of problem I am facing:

- 1. if I am setting image till category_id.equals(2)
     (here only 1 if else statement)
     then its showing the image in else condition only
- 2. if I am setting image for all till category_id.equals(7)
     (here multiple if, else if condition as in question)
     then its not showing any images at all.

Why it is happening? I am not able to get it.Please help me...

Any help is greatly appreciable.

```
private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Contents> tableofcontents;
public TocAdapter(Activity activity, List<Contents> tableofcontents) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.tableofcontents = tableofcontents;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return tableofcontents == null ? 0 : tableofcontents.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return tableofcontents.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tableofcontents_view, null);
    ImageView thumbNail = (ImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    Contents m = tableofcontents.get(position);
    String id = tableofcontents.get(position).getCategory_id();
    Log.d(TAG,"m Check :"+m.getCategory_id());
    Log.d(TAG,"tggCheck :"+tableofcontents.get(position).getCategory_id());
    if(tableofcontents.get(position).getCategory_id().equals(1)) {
        Glide.with(activity)
                .load(R.drawable.novels)
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .into(thumbNail);
    }else if(tableofcontents.get(position).getCategory_id().equals(2)){
        Glide.with(activity)
                .load(R.drawable.verses)
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .into(thumbNail);
    }else if(tableofcontents.get(position).getCategory_id().equals(3)) {
        Glide.with(activity)
                .load(R.drawable.songs)
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .into(thumbNail);
    }else if(tableofcontents.get(position).getCategory_id().equals(4)) {
        Glide.with(activity)
                .load(R.drawable.stories)
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .into(thumbNail);
    }else if(tableofcontents.get(position).getCategory_id().equals(5)) {
        Glide.with(activity)
                .load(R.drawable.plays)
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .into(thumbNail);
    }else if(tableofcontents.get(position).getCategory_id().equals(6)) {
        Glide.with(activity)
                .load(R.drawable.essay)
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .into(thumbNail);
    }else if(tableofcontents.get(position).getCategory_id().equals(7)) {
        Glide.with(activity)
                .load(R.drawable.others)
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .into(thumbNail);
    }
    name.setText(m.getName());
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: equals() methods take String as parameter. looks like here You're taking Integer as parameter.

Comment: @msh.nayan what a nonsens ... it takes Object not String

Comment: Do you know that we have `switch` statment in java?

Comment: Working superb...what a silly mistake i was doing...thanks @msh.nayan

Answer (score 0):

Use `==` when comparing integers